# Generate CRUD UI and REST API from a schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, schema

I would like to define a couple of schemas and automatically generate simple tables and forms from that automatically retrieve and store data via a standard REST API in a database (ideally a MongoDB).

The schema could for example look like this:

```
{
  "title": "AudioInputDevices",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "channelCount": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "channelCount"]
}
```

(But it could of course be more complicated and have properties of type array or object.)

## UI

From the example schema, it should generate UI elements like this:

```
+----+-----------------------+--------------+
| id |         name          | channelCount |
+----+-----------------------+--------------+
|  0 | Built-in Microphone   |      1       |
|  1 | Behringer XR18        |     18       |
|  2 | Sennheiser Stereo Mic |      2       |
+----+-----------------------+--------------+

  [Add]   [Edit]   [Delete]
```

The `Add` button opens a form like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
|      Create New Record         |
+--------------------------------+
|           name: [          ]   |
|   channelCount: [          ]   |
|                                |
|            [Submit]            |
+--------------------------------+
```

The `Edit` button opens a form like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
|             Edit Record            |
+------------------------------------+
|           name: [Behringer XR18]   |
|   channelCount: [            18]   |
|                                    |
|              [Submit]              |
+------------------------------------+
```

## REST API

The table should automatically load its data from `GET /api/AudioInputDevices` which would return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Built-in Microphone",
    "channelCount": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Behringer XR18",
    "channelCount": 18
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Sennheiser Stereo Mic",
    "channelCount": 2
  }
]
```

When the `Add` form is submitted the data from the form should be submitted via `POST /api/AudioInputDevices` with a json like this:

```
{
  "name": "Headset Mic",
  "channelCount": 1
}
```

The response would be:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Headset Mic",
  "channelCount": 1
}
```

and should be added to the table in the UI automatically.

When the `Edit` form is submitted the data from the form should be submitted via `PUT /api/AudioInputDevices/:idOfSelectedItem` (e.g. `/api/AudioInputDevices/3` with a json like this:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "channelCount": 1
}
```

The response would be:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Hello",
  "channelCount": 1
}
```

and the entry in the table should be updated accordingly automatically.

When the `Delete` button is pressed, a request should be sent to `DELETE /api/AudioInputDevices/:idOfSelectedItem` and if a status code 200 is received the element should be removed from the table in the UI automatically.

## Database

A request to `GET /api/AudioInputDevices` should create a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.AudioInputDevices.find({})
```

A request to `GET /api/AudioInputDevices/123` should create a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.AudioInputDevices.find({"_id": 123})
```

A request to `POST /api/AudioInputDevices` should create a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.AudioInputDevices.insertOne({
  name: "New Microphone",
  channelCount: 1
})
```

A request to `PUT /api/AudioInputDevices/22` should create a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.AudioInputDevices.updateOne(
  { id: 22 },
  { $set: { name: "Updated Microphone", channelCount: 20 } }
)
```

A request to `DELETE /api/AudioInputDevices/2` should create a MongoDB query like this:

```
db.AudioInputDevices.deleteOne({ id: 2 })
```

## Ideas

[express-restify-mongoose](https://florianholzapfel.github.io/express-restify-mongoose/) seems to be great for creating complete MONGODB-connected REST APIs from a Mongoose Schema.
[UI-Schema](https://ui-schema.bemit.codes/) seems to be great for generating tables and forms including frontend validation. It's based on JSON Schema, extended by a couple of UI-specific keywords.

But even if I were to write a UI-Schema to Mongoose Schema converter, the UI still wouldn't automatically be connected to the API.

The whole idea seems like such a trivial and obvious problem, that has most likely been solved before I would guess. I'm just not able to find anything online. Does anyone of you have any experience with this or ideas on how to solve it without too many hacks?

**Edit:**
I would prefer a solution using a JSON-based REST API, React.js frontend and MongoDB for storage in the backend, but I am open to alternative solutions. It's just important that it needs to be a JS-based browser frontend and a JS-based nodejs backend.

Comment: Sounds more like an entire software solution. I doubt anyone would spend the time to do this here. Sound' like you already describe the problem and solution pretty well. Just take the time to write the code.

Comment: I was hoping to find some experts who could point me into the right direction. I could of course write something that matches the basics that I described, but I think it would be a lot of work to maintain something like this. Especially considering that in practice you'd probably have to add a ton of extra code, for example to handle hashing and masking of password fields. I would like to build upon existing code that is maintained by the open source community as much as possible.

Comment: It's not that trivial I'm afraid. Even the "Generate UI" part will be very specific to the platform and FE framework. And considering stability/maturity of these frameworks, this part alone is "a lot of work to maintain" regardless of you do it yourself or anybody else does it for you. If by "pointing to the right direction" you mean "recommend a tool or library", it violates SO policy.